# How to fix this mysql error in ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: server, apt, dpkg, mysql

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please don't remove the formatting; it improves readability.

Comment: Why are you insisting on making the question harder to read?

Answer (score 4):

The error message

> debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)

is saying that, you're trying to install mysql from a very little terminal window which doesn't have required height (and/or width)  to display the questions needed to configure mysql. Without proper answers to those questions mysql configuration file could not be saved and without configuration settings file, mysql will be failing. probably you're using guake with little height or something.

Install mysql with a proper sized terminal and configure it answering the questions, mostly root password. The problem should go.